# I quit my job because of a workplace bully. Now that she has been fired, my boss offered me my job back. Should I take it?

Tags: job-offer, quitting, employment

My boss called me to tell me they were firing the bully. She asked me if I would be willing to return to my position if they offered me a 8% (approx $1.50) pay raise. I worry that it will be awkward. Should I stick to my decision about quitting?

Comment: This is off topic as your asking about a specific choice.  I will say if the main reason you left is gone and your invited back with more cash to boot, I would ask you *Why not?*

Comment: off topic yes but this shouldn't even be a questionable thing. Take the raise and be happy

Comment: Have a rider on your contract specifying an immediate excuse from your duty, at full pay, if you are forced to work with the bully again; then accept if the job was good.

Comment: Do you have a job currently?  If so, do you like it?  How is the pay comparatively?

Comment: The question is very specific, however there is a topic which his new here: What if management addresses a problem successfully and honestly.

Comment: @Sascha True, but even in the general sense, I'm not sure that question is a good fit for SE.  Whether or not you want to go back to a given job after the issues that lead you to quit have been addressed will vary depending on the situation; it can't really be answered in a general case.

Comment: More clarity on the situation: The bully has been a company problem for a while. I quit three days ago and management approached me (the same day) to let me know that they are firing the bully today. It’s been a very quick turn around time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds to me like management solved the problem by firing the employee, and admitted the problem to you by stating that and offering your job back in the same conversation.

So I'll echo the above answers/comments with a 'Why not?'  Keep in mind that experts here only have about two sentences to base this answer on, so we're missing a lot of context that hasn't been stated yet.

If it matters you can request a letter be added to your HR file saying that your first voluntary termination was due to a workplace bully which management later resolved.

Answer (score 11):

If you liked your previous job, then take your job back.

If you didn't like it (regardless of the bully), then go find something else.

If you take your old job back, it won't be awkward (they seem to want you back after all).

Answer (score 3):

That depends on a number of things.

1. Is this job better than the one you have now, do you even have a job now.
2. Did they dismiss your earlier concerns or did you not raise the concerns and just quit.
3. Have they addressed any other reasons you left.
4. Will leaving your current job, assuming you have one, affect the possibility you might leave again.